# how can I translate my function into a more complex main() function?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I've been already trying unsuccessfully for a couple of hours to translate this code into separated functions that I can call with a main() function

so this code works for me but when I try to make it into a if **name** == "**main**" function I keep getting errors:

```
filename = 'some_text.txt'
file = open(filename, 'r')
txt = file.read()
file.close()

def countwords(txt):
    import string 
    txt = txt.lower()  
    word = txt.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).split()
    count = {}
    for i in word:
      if i in count:
       count[i] += 1
      else: count[i] = 1
    return count 

countwords(txt)
```

how could I translate this into a function that reads the text, another function that counts the words and execute all through a main() function?
similar to this structure:

```
def readfile(text)
    return

def wordcount(lines)
    return

def main()
    readfile(text)
    wordcount(lines)
    if __name__== "__main__" :
main()
```

Thanks for the help! I hope I didn't make any errors in the question...

Comment: What does your program return? Did you run it?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
"trying unsuccessfully" is not a problem specification; that suggests a local tutor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save some lines of code by writing your open file code as:

```
with open('some_text.txt') as file:
    file.read()
```

The overall program could look like this:

```
def read_file():
    with open('test_file.txt') as file:
        return file.read()


def word_count(file):
    import string
    txt = file.lower()
    word = txt.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).split()
    count = {}
    for i in word:
        if i in count:
            count[i] += 1
        else:
            count[i] = 1
    return count


def main():
    wc = word_count(read_file())
    print(wc)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = ''

def readfile(text)
    filename = 'some_text.text'
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    return

def wordcount()
    import string 
    text = text.lower()  
    word = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).split()
    count = {}
    for i in word:
      if i in count:
        count[i] += 1
      else: 
        count[i] = 1
    return count 
    

def main()
    readfile()
    wordcount()
    
main()
```